# Variable doesn't exist in the current context while debugging in Razor template ( not MVC , no Views Folder)

Tags: c#, linq, json.net, razorengine

I use RazorEngine C# to bind a template at run time but while debugging I can't see a variable value neither get an exception. Here is my code:

```
    JObject jsonOb = JObject.Parse(modelOutPut); // modelOutPut is JSON string
        JArray brandPerformanceArr = (JArray)jsonOb["STATS"]["BrandProductPerformance"];
        List<ProductPefRec> records = brandPerformanceArr.ToObject<List<ProductPefRec>>();
        string anyVar = "anyvalue";//Debugger here can't see records variable,
   // when I put it in watch , it displays "the name "records" doesn't exist in the current context.
```

It's been days now trying to solve this issue, Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the json that is in `modelOutPut`?

Comment: sometimes the debugger doesn't show the value of a variable if it's not later used.